# Data getting inserted multiple times - android, php

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my project, I'm sending data from an android device and it is inserted into a database using a php script. But the same data is inserted twice. ([please see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDwxQ.png))
What is wrong with my code?

Android:

```
try {
    String data=URLEncoder.encode("name",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Name,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("family",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Family,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("city",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(City,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("ostan",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Ostan,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("tel",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Tel,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("sef",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(sef1,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("bod",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(bodjeh1,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("tab",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(tabgh,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("img",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(imgs,  "UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("imgf",  "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fimage,  "UTF-8");
URL link=new URL(MainActivity.url+"/app/order.php");
URLConnection con=link.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wrw=new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
wrw.write(data);
wrw.flush();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String l="";
while((l=br.readLine())!=null){
    sb.append(l);
}
r=sb.toString();
br.close();
```

Code for insertion - php

```
   $name=$_POST['name'];
    $family_name=$_POST['family'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $ostan=$_POST['ostan'];
    $tel=$_POST['tel'];
    $comment=$_POST['sef'];
    $bod=$_POST['bod'];
    $tab=$_POST['tab'];
    $img=$_POST['img'];
    $imgf=$_POST['imgf'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO `customer_table`(`id`, `name`, `family_name`, `city`, `ostan`, `tel`, `comment`,`bodjeh`,`tabagheh`,`imag_f`,`image`)
     VALUES ('','$name','$family_name','$city','$ostan','$tel','$comment','$bod','$tab','$imgf','$img')";
```

Comment: Add a log before link.openConnection() to check how many times this code executes

Comment: 12-16 01:06:56.203: W/CursorWrapperInner(2123): Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-16 01:06:56.323: D/dalvikvm(2123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 56% free 9184K/20807K, paused 10ms
12-16 01:06:56.323: I/dalvikvm-heap(2123): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.013MB for 1043122-byte allocation
12-16 01:06:56.343: D/dalvikvm(2123): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 51% free 10203K/20807K, paused 0ms+0ms
12-16 01:06:56.413: D/dalvikvm(2123): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 46% free 11241K/20807K, paused 0ms
12-16 01:06:56.463: D/dalvikvm(2123): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1026K, 44% free 11694K/20807K, paused 0ms+0ms

Comment: This log doesn't help. You should add some logs by yourself to debug your code and find out where the problem is

Comment: Can we have a little more of your PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below method to send data to server

First convert your request json into simple map like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", Name);.....so on
```

Then use below method to call the Webservice.

```
 private JSONObject sendRequest(String urlString, Map<String, String> map, String fileKey,  File file) {
            StringBuilder strData= null;
            JSONObject resObj = null;
            try {
                Log.i("Send request", urlString+"="+map);
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(50000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                if(map == null)
                {
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                }
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String k = entry.getKey();
                    String v = entry.getValue();
                    reqEntity.addPart(k, new StringBody(v));
                }

                if(file != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(fileKey))
                {
                    FileBody filebody = new FileBody(file, "image/*");
                    reqEntity.addPart(fileKey, filebody);
                }

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength() + "");
                conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                reqEntity.writeTo(os);
                os.close();
                conn.connect();
                if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String sResponse;
                    strData = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        strData = strData.append(sResponse);
                    }
                }
                if(strData != null)
                    resObj = new JSONObject(strData.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resObj;
        }
```

As your php code you need to do :

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 if(count($result) > 0)
 {
    echo "1"; 
 }else
 { 
   echo "0";
 }
```

Comment: @Sadegh sarvi : I think your problem is at php side it may execute query two times then only possible.

Comment: Please paste some what more code of php after "$sql" initialization

Comment: mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_query($sql)==TRUE){
 echo "1";
}else{
 echo "0";
}

Comment: Yes you did (mysql_query($sql) two times you need to do var $bool = mysql_query($sql);  if( $bool==TRUE) then it will work